# Resizing to page width for print style sheet

Tags: javascript, css, printing

So [I've got a page](http://rampion.github.com/4eCharSheet/empty.html) that shows an image with some absolutely positioned text on top of it.

I want to write a print style sheet for it so that:

1. the image is resized to fit the width of the page
2. the text is repositioned and resized to maintain relative position and size with the image behind it

So I know I can do (1) with just `max-width: 100%`, but I'm not sure how to accomplish (2).  I'm okay with using some javascript if necessary, but I wanted to know if there's a way to do this in pure CSS.  If I do need to use javascript, what can I hook to check for the pixel width of the image in the printed page?  Just use the calculated width as normal?

---

And yes, this question might be more appropriate for [DocType](http://doctype.com), but [I've yet to get any help over there](http://doctype.com/resizing-page-width-print-style-sheet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was that I had set `overflow: auto` in the main div, which was causing the contents to overflow the printed page.

To fix it, all I needed to do was set `overflow: none`.

The `overflow: auto` was what was making it print like

[image: http://rampion.github.com/4eCharSheet/doc/printer-problem.png]
<sub>(source: [github.com](http://rampion.github.com/4eCharSheet/doc/printer-problem.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I think you could happily leave it to the printer driver *if* you trim off the whitespace around the images, and then replace the margins on-screen with css, and the remove it again in a print-media stylesheet. Buiding-in the page margins is going to cause problems.